# Using two or more images on a page with prototype object of javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, tooltip

I am using this script.

http://digitalhymn.com/argilla/tipmage/

**It is not possible to apply Tipmage to more than one image in a single page**

Is this possible to apply this class to more than one image?

Thanks

Comment: Does your question answer itself? It seems to say "Is it possible? It is not possible".

Comment: "It is not possible to apply Tipmage to more than one image in a single page" From their site, it is not possible!

Comment: It is written as a known issue. I have tried to fix this issue but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

did you know this plugin

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/

http://www.flipbit.co.uk/jquery-image-annotation.html#

Comment: For this too, users are complaining the same issue ( more than one image ) .    http://blog.flipbit.co.uk/2009/03/jquery-image-annotation-plugin.html